# Git: how to merge other repository's remote master branch into local master without contaminating it

Tags: git

I have two github repository.

One is client repo and the other is server repo.

client repo is currently in local and server repo is in remote.

I want to manage two repository into one.

How to merge two repo like below?

---

#### client repo git commits

[branch master]

client-root

[branch dev]

client-root -> 1 -> 2 -> client-HEAD

---

#### server repo git commits

[branch master]

server-root -> 3 -> 4 -> server-HEAD

---

#### what i want

[branch master]

client-root

[branch dev]

client-root -> 1 -> 2 -> client-HEAD -> server-root -> 3 -> 4 -> server-HEAD

---

thank you for reading!

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something, because this seems like this is merging commits with no shared history - which I would expect to have conflicts all over the place and ultimately not do anything useful. Do these repos have ANY shared commits?

Comment: @Vlad274 fortunately, there is no shared commit. if two has any shared commit, then there is any way to merge these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the state you describe, this will create the desired state in your local (client) repo:

1. `git checkout dev` - Switch to dev branch
2. `git cherry-pick ..server/master` - Take all commits reachable from `server/master` and put them on top of the current branch